# Compare Arrays with array_diff - but only first chars

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, csv, diff

I got following situation.
I got a csv file and some data in a mysql database.
I want to load the csv file and compare it to a row in the mysql database.

The csv file got following types of data:

```
eet003 240
eet003 180
eet003 280
eet299 100
```

But in the database the data looks like this:

```
eet003
eet299
```

So both datas a stored in arrays.

```
$array1
$array2
```

And I want to compare the two arrays and save the result in a third array.
   $diff = array_diff($array1, $array2)

But I onlny want to compare the first 6 chars of the data. So right now eet003 240 is different from eet003. But for me its the same. I only need eet003 e.g.

How could I archieve that? I now the substr function but array1 is created the follwing way:

```
$rows = array();    //aray for csv file
$rows = file('pinesite_eet.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);    //write csv in array
```

I don't know how du cut the string from the csv when it's loaded in the array.
The second array is written from a mysql_query.
Any suggestions on how I could do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be easier to just modify the data. This removes the space and everything after in each element:

```
$rows = preg_replace('/ .*/', '', $rows);
```

Then `array_diff()` should work as expected.

Comment: In the csv output I got something like that - csv output $rows

[87] => eet090 [88] => eet090 [89] => eet090 [90] => eet090 [91]

Rows from database: $dbinhalt

Array ( [0] => eet013 [1] => eet090 [2] => eet091 [3] => eet092 [4] => 

No my array_diff function shows the following:

eet090
eet091

But eet0090, and eet0091 are both in the csv and the database. So why I get this as a result of the comparison?

    $diff2 = array_diff($dbinhalt, $rows);
    foreach($diff2 as $ergebnis){
    echo $ergebnis . '</br>';
    }

Comment: Post a snippet of a `var_dump` of both arrays.

Comment: Ah :) Got it. Thanks for the hint. The $rows was - [90]=> string(7) "eet090 " - the die $dbinhalt was -  [1]=> string(6) "eet090" - 

It was related to the $rows = preg_replace('/ .*/', '', $rows);

Don't know why, but I got a blankspace in the preg_replace('/ .*/', 'blankspace'. Removed it and everything works fine!!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

I think something like this should work:

(Here I just use [`array_udiff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php) with a anonymous function where I only use the first part of the file data and compare it with the database data)

```
<?php

    $result = array_udiff($fileData, $dbData, function($a, $b) {
        if(strcasecmp(explode(" ", $a)[0], $b) == 0)
            return 0;
        return strcasecmp(explode(" ", $a)[0], $b);
    });

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for you tipp. I will try that! Don't understand that fully, but will try to get through.